SwiftUI: withAnimation in parent view results in animation in child view
This code presents a grid of buttons in a sheet and updates the parent view's view model and view.  Touching a grid button always redraws the sheet's view even though its state doesn't (shouldn't?) change, and with animation even though none is configured in the sheet's view.  This code is complete, and I tested on real device.
class MessageModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var text = ""
    func setText(message: String){
        text = message
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var label = ""
    @State private var showPresets = false
    @State private var currentDetent: PresentationDetent = .fraction(0.05)
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = MessageModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(label)
            
            Button {
                showPresets = true
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .onReceive(viewModel.$text, perform: { text in
            withAnimation {
                label = text
            }
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $showPresets) {
            PresetsView(onDismiss : { self.presetsViewDidDismiss() }, buttonAction: saveMessage)
                .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.05), .fraction(0.6), .large], selection: $currentDetent)
            .presentationDragIndicator(.hidden)
        }
    }
    
    private func presetsViewDidDismiss() {
        print("Presets view was dismissed")
    }
    
    private func saveMessage(message: String) {
        viewModel.setText(message: message)
    }
}

struct PresetsView: View {
    @State private var selectedPresetCatagoriesArray = ["Topic1", "Topic2", "Topic3"]
    
    @State private var setMessage = ""
    
    var onDismiss: () -> Void
    let buttonAction: (String) -> Void
    
    let presets = Presets()
    
    var body: some View {
        let columns = [
            GridItem(.flexible()),
            GridItem(.flexible()),
            GridItem(.flexible())
        ]
        
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(selectedPresetCatagoriesArray, id: \.self) { category in
                Text(category.uppercased())
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(presets.getPresets(for: category.lowercased()), id: \.self) { preset in
                        Button(action: {
                            setMessage = preset.message
                            Task {
                                buttonAction(setMessage)
                            }
                        }) {
                            VStack() {
                                Circle()
                                    .frame(width: 55, height: 55)
                                    .overlay {
                                        Image(systemName: preset.image)
                                            .font(.system(size: 25))
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    }
                                Text(preset.label)
                                    .font(.footnote)
                                
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Divider()
                    .background(Color.gray)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            
        }
        .defaultScrollAnchor(.top)
        .onDisappear() {
            onDismiss()
        }
    }
}

struct Preset: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    let label: String
    var image: String
    let message: String
}

struct Presets {
    let presetsTopic1 = [
        Preset(label: "1", image: "1.circle.fill", message: "One"),
        Preset(label: "2", image: "2.circle.fill", message: "Two"),
        Preset(label: "3", image: "3.circle.fill", message: "Three")
    ]
    
    let presetsTopic2 = [
        Preset(label: "1", image: "1.circle.fill", message: "One"),
        Preset(label: "2", image: "2.circle.fill", message: "Two"),
        Preset(label: "3", image: "3.circle.fill", message: "Three")
    ]
    
    let presetsTopic3 = [
        Preset(label: "1", image: "1.circle.fill", message: "One"),
        Preset(label: "2", image: "2.circle.fill", message: "Two"),
        Preset(label: "3", image: "3.circle.fill", message: "Three")
    ]
    
    func getPresets(for type: String) -> [Preset] {
        switch type {
        case "topic1":
            return presetsTopic1
        case "topic2":
            return presetsTopic2
        case "topic3":
            return presetsTopic3
        default:
            return []
        }
    }
}


Setting 'label = text' in ContentView's .onReceive block causes PresetsView to be refreshed, especially visible if withAnimation is also configured (as in sample).  Grid buttons often, but not always, animate into position.

Use @State var text = "", ObservableObject is only for when you need a  Combine pipeline or delegate callbacks.
